# Changing class from character to numeric when using zoo

Tags: class, events, character, numeric, zoo

Does anyone know how to change a colum of a zoo object from character to numeric?

- Needed for use in the "evetstudies" function.
  I create the variable as so:

> x <-na.omit(df[,(1:3)])
> Returns<-zoo(x,order.by = as.Date(E_S$DATE, format="%Y/%m/%d"))

Which gives:

> str(Returns)

```
‘zoo’ series from 2021-04-06 to 2022-11-22
  Data: chr [1:415, 1] "  1.733" "1.733" "  1.493" " -0.919" " -0.928" " -1.873" "  0.725" ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr "R_TEKNA"
  Index:  Date[1:415], format: "2021-04-06" "2021-04-07" "2021-04-08" "2021-04-09" "2021-04-12" "2021-04-13" ...
```

---Data is numeric before running the zoo function.
How can i change the chr (Data: chr [1:415, 1]) to num?

Tried using as.numeric() or numeric(), but wont work. (nothing changes)

Answer (score 0):

Eventually found it out if anyone in the future has the same problem.

- When using zoo the input data can only contain numeric variables. (one specific type).
- Therefore, the data used for defining the index (Like your DATES), have to come from an individual df.

I made the mistake of including a dates variable in the df used for the matrix. Did not think of making an individual df for the dates